# What does "AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'worksheet' " mean?

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-colaboratory

What does this mean?
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'worksheet'
This error comes up when I run my code and I can't figure out what it means.

The entire error is:

```
      2 Jan = Jan.worksheet('01')
----> 3 while Jan.worksheet() !=  31:
      4   Jan = get_as_dataframe(Jan)
      5   Jan = pd.DataFrame(Jan)
```

AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'worksheet'

[How to write a python for loop to reformat 31 different google sheets with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57400007/how-to-write-a-python-for-loop-to-reformat-31-different-google-sheets-with-panda)
This is a link to another question off of the same code.

```
Jan = gc.open_by_url('with held for privacy reasons')
Jan = Jan.worksheet('01')
#for worksheet in Jan.worksheet:
#while Jan.worksheet is not 31:
if Jan.worksheet !=  31:
  Jan = get_as_dataframe(Jan)
  Jan = pd.DataFrame(Jan)
  day_month = Jan.worksheet
  new_header = Jan.iloc[0]
  Jan = Jan[1:]
  Jan.columns = new_header
  col_list = ['Time',   'Roof(in)', 'East(in)', 'West(in)', 'North(in)',    'Roof(out)',    'East(out)',    'West(out)',    'North(out)']
  Jan = Jan[col_list]
  Jan = Jan.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
  Jan = Jan[:-2]
  Jan.columns = ['DateTime',    'Business_Location_In', 'East_Location_In', 'West_Location_In', 'North_Location_In',    
                   'Business_Location_Out', 'East_Location_Out',    'West_Location_Out',    'North_Location_Out']
  Jan['DateTime'] = Jan['DateTime'].str.slice(6)
  Jan['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime('2019-01- ' + worksheet+ Jan['DateTime'])
  for filename in Jan:
    Jan['Jan'+ day_month] = filenames
  while Jan.worksheet() < 31:
    Jan = Jan.worksheet(day_month + 1)
elif Jan.worksheet == 31:
  Jan = get_as_dataframe(Jan)
  Jan = pd.DataFrame(Jan)
  day_month = Jan.worksheet
  new_header = Jan.iloc[0]
  Jan = Jan[1:]
  Jan.columns = new_header
  col_list = ['Time',   'Roof(in)', 'East(in)', 'West(in)', 'North(in)',    'Roof(out)',    'East(out)',    'West(out)',    'North(out)']
  Jan = Jan[col_list]
  Jan = Jan.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
  Jan = Jan[:-2]
  Jan.columns = ['DateTime',    'Business_Location_In', 'East_Location_In', 'West_Location_In', 'North_Location_In',    
                   'Business_Location_Out', 'East_Location_Out',    'West_Location_Out',    'North_Location_Out']
  Jan['DateTime'] = Jan['DateTime'].str.slice(6)
  Jan['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime('2019-01- ' + worksheet+ Jan['DateTime'])
  for filename in Jan: #this sets the file name to Jan and the day of month
    Jan['Jan'+ day_month] = filenames
print(filenames)
```

I just need to know how to fix this problem in my code and if someone could also solve my other code problem, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm gonna level with you. I think you should burn what you've got and start over. I can't tell you what the right way to do this is, because I can't tell at all what you're trying to do. If you really want help you should post an example of your data structure and an example of what you want to produce.

Comment: okay, thanks for your honest opinion, also, if you go to the link of my other question, it will explain what the code does.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error tells you that somewhere you have a `Workbook` object, and you are trying to access its `worksheet` attribute, i.e. `Worksheet.worksheet`. However, `Worksheet` has no attibute `worksheet` to access.

The error only tells you *what* is wrong. The rest of the traceback tells you *where* it is wrong. My *guess* is that the object referenced in the error is `Jan`. If you provide the rest of the traceback, one of us here on SO could probably tell you with certainty.

Comment: the rest of the traceback is on the link, but thanks for your input. Additionally, how would I fix my code, with my coding being the one above?

Comment: @UserX Looking at what you posted, `Jan` is definitely the problem, or least the attempts to access the attribute it does not have. I'm not experienced with using Google tools, so the only feedback I have is coming from an abstract level -- identify how you can access one sheet, then ask yourself what makes each sheet different and how you can change that factor in a loop. In a separate question, you might highlight that specific part of the code, and ask how to iterate over the pages withholding the rest of the code that actually formats the sheet (since that part is working).